# How to remove commas and brackets from a list ( hmatrix )

Tags: haskell, ghci, hmatrix

#### For plotting a graphic in gnuplot

I'm trying to print this matrix into a file, but for it to be executed into gnuplot I need to create a file without the commas and brackets, how do I do that?

```
*install hmatrix
*install hmatrix-special
*import Numeric.LinearAlgebra

(5><2)
 [   0.12130139101653795, -3.9532277879855915e-2
 , -9.943512129289413e-2, -1.8736674261187188e-2
 ,   0.21650870755682688,  -7.774998273846949e-3
 ,  -0.19540767578866855,  -4.889335919164774e-2
 , -4.296730149180415e-2,    0.11493730960653939 ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will print out the matrix with each row on its own line:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

import Numeric.LinearAlgebra

m :: Matrix Double
m = (5><2)
 [   0.12130139101653795, -3.9532277879855915e-2
 , -9.943512129289413e-2, -1.8736674261187188e-2
 ,   0.21650870755682688,  -7.774998273846949e-3
 ,  -0.19540767578866855,  -4.889335919164774e-2
 , -4.296730149180415e-2,    0.11493730960653939 ]

printMatrix m = do
  putStrLn $ unlines $ map (unwords . map show . toList )  (toRows m)

test = printMatrix m
```